# Copy content of Multidimensional array to single array

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I need to copy the Particular String content of `CryptoTables` 2D array.

Here is the 2D array :-

```
#define CRYPTOENTRIES 10
unsigned char CryptoTables [CRYPTOENTRIES][7]= {"Sgehd",
                                                "Fshdj",
                                                "Hdbdh",
                                                "Gshsi",
                                                "Hiufs",
                                                "Rtygd",
                                                "Tyygf",
                                                "Gfftn",
                                                "Ffyhs",
                                                "Fghhx"};
```

How to copy the content of any particular location of above given 2D array to another single array string (`char array[10];`)?

For example if I have to copy the 3rd String in `CryptoTables` i.e `Hdbdh` to another array string.?

Comment: `strcpy(array, CryptoTables[2]);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access each row of 2D array `foo` as `foo[i]`.
So to copy the 3rd string of `CryptoTables` you can use this code:

```
char bar[7];
strcpy(bar, CryptoTables[2]);
```

array `bar` must be large enough to hold the string pointed by `CryptoTables[2]` **including** a terminating `\0` byte.

Answer (score -1):

All of your entries are 5 characters length, so the new array should be  `char arr[6]` (5 characters + null terminator byte). If you want to copy it, just address the wanted string: `CryptoTables[2]` (third location), and use `strncpy` to copy it to `arr` - read about it here:

http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-strings/c-strncpy-function/

Comment: `strcpy` will copy the string pointed to by `CryptoTables[2]`, including the terminating null byte `\0`, to the buffer pointed to by `arr`. But since length of `arr` is `5` this will lead to `buffer overrun`

Comment: You are right, didn't have the time to write it. Adding it